# Which PDF/DVI viewers have spelling error or homonym detectors?

Tags: spelling

Sometimes it is easy to miss a spelling error in TeX. Which PDF/DVI editors let you a second check? Many allow you to spell check the input field in a form. I want the main document to be checked.

And does any reader detect  homonyms? As in flagging there/their/they're.

A MAC solution is provided below, a Windows port was not found.
A paid version is [this](http://try67.blogspot.com/2009/07/acrobat-spell-check-suite.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/), IMHO the best PDF viewer for Mac, has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any. As PDF/DVI output is in principle unchangeable, there's no need of spell-correcting it. You should use spelling correction in your source editor.

Comment: Sorry, Skim has, as Daniel said in his answer. But I don't see much use in checking the output instead of the source...

Comment: You can use synchronization to jump to the right line in the TeX document.

Comment: If you use Skim, you're probably also using TeXWorks (or TextMate, or...), which uses the same Cocoa spell-checking engine.

Comment: No, TeXworks can't use the Cocoa engine.

Comment: @NVaughan: when one spellchecks the source directly, all the \*TeX commands rather muddy the waters.  The text that *should* be spellchecked is usually exactly the text that appears in the output, so spellchecking there is more natural/convenient in some ways.

Comment: TexShop an Co. have their own PDF viewers; you use Skim if you are probably also using vi or emacs :-)